# How to generate R file correctly with Gradle while I only put resources under src/test

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Here is my directory structure. 
Since I don't need any resource when I'm compiling android java source, there is no any resource was put under src/main

```
src/
  main/
     java

  test/
     java
     resources/
         res/
            layout
```

I only need to use some layout id while I'm compiling/running test case.

ex:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_content, container, false);
}
```

Here is my build.gradle of my module level.
But it can't run my test case successfully.
**I always got some error messages about can not find symbol variable(my layout resource name.).**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 26

    android {
        sourceSets {
            test {
                res.srcDirs = ['src/test/resources/res']
            }
        }
        testOptions {
            unitTests {
                includeAndroidResources = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**If I put layout resources under src/main/res, then everything is going well.**

But I'd like my resources keep under src/test/resources/res/layout, since I don't use them when I'm compiling java code.

Is there any way can help me solve my request?

If you need more information, just let me know :) Thanks

Comment: did you tried clean project? and rebuild?

Comment: yes, I tried to clean project and rebuild when I changed my build.gradle every time.